# Aurelia - Change the color of the selected row in a table

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I am using Aurelia v4.6.1 with Typescript in a.Net core project. I have a component that retrieves data from an external source and displays it in a table using a repeat.for attribute.

Now I want to highlight the row that has been selected (clicked). On my view model I have a documents property of type Document[] that holds all the documents displayed in the grid, and I have a selectedDocument property of type Document that should hold the last selected document. This is set in a click event on the row setSelected.

My view is as follows:

```
<template>
<require from="../../resources/valueconverters/itemIdFormat"></require>
<require from="./documentData.css"></require>
<h1>Patient Documents</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from DME.</p>

<p if.bind="!documents"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table if.bind="documents" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Patient</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="document of documents" click.trigger="setSelected(document)" class="${($document.title == $selectedDocument.title) ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}">
            <td>${ document.itemId | itemIdFormat }</td>
            <td>${ document.title }</td>
            <td>${ document.patient.lastName}, ${ document.patient.firstName }</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My ViewModel class is:

```
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { BindingEngine, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(HttpClient, BindingEngine)
export class DocumentData {
public documents: Document[];
public selectedDocument: Document;
public bindingEngine

constructor(http: HttpClient, bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
    this.selectedDocument = null;
    let subscription = this.bindingEngine
        .propertyObserver(this, 'selectedDocument')
        .subscribe(this.selectedDocumentChanged);


    http.fetch('/api/Data/PatientDocuments')
        .then(result => result.json() as Promise<Document[]>)
        .then(data => {
            this.documents = data;
        });
}

setSelected(selected: Document) {
    this.selectedDocument = selected;
}

selectedDocumentChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
   // this.documents.forEach(function (d) {
   //     d.isCurrent = d === newValue;
   // })
}
}
```

As you can see in the view html, I have set the class attribute on the table row element with:

```
class="${($document.title == $selectedDocument.title) ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}"
```

However for some reason this always returns true so all rows are highlighted.

So I tried this instead:

```
class="${$document.isCurrent ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}"
```

Then I used the binding engine subscribe function on the `selectedDocument` property, setting it to run `selectedDocumentChanged` method, to set the isCurrent property on each document in the list manually whenever the `selectedDocument` property is changed. Notice however that this is commented out. This is because the `this` variable is not in scope in the subscriber changed method so I can't use it.

So I am a bit stuck. What is the correct way to highlight the selected row? I guess it might be possible using a nested component repeated for each row, but I would prefer to be able to achieve this all in this component.

Comment: It really looks like you're on the right track - I'm a bit confused about why `this` is out of scope in your `selecteddocumentChanged` method - it shouldn't be. However - `newValue` may not be in scope - can you switch to `this.document.forEach((d) => {` - so you're using an arrow function instead? This'll keep the scope of your parent method then.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why it is out of scope either. The actual error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documents' of undefined (the 'this' is undefined). I tried with the arrow function syntax but it made no difference. Because the 'this' is undefined it doesn't get to that part of the statement anyway.

Comment: Instead of using `this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver` can you try the `@observable` decorator? That'll use the same `selectedDocumentChanged()` method without the need to use the Binding Engine. Might solve the scope problem.

Comment: Yes that does solve the problem thanks! 'this' is in scope when you use @observable and the isCurrent property is now getting set correctly. However the view doesn't update automatically as it doesn't recalculate class="${$document.isCurrent ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}". Any ideas on how I do this?

Comment: I've quickly just tested that in my App and it works for me. Does it need to be `${document...` rather than `${$document...`?

Comment: I've posted the above as an answer, I can update if the `$` doesn't sort if for you.

Comment: the single $ works - thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - the scope issue you're getting with the `selectedDocumentChanged()` method is because you're using the Binding Engine. If you use the observable decorator instead like below, `this` will no longer be out of scope;

```
import {observable} from "aurelia-framework";

export class DocumentData {

    @observable selectedDocument;

    // Your other code

    selectedDocumentChanged(newVal, oldVal) {
        this.documents.forEach(function (d) { // no longer out of scope
            d.isCurrent = d === newValue;
        })
    }
}
```

Secondly - in your template you don't need to prefix your properties with a `$`. This is only used when you want to use string interpolation within your templates. If you're looping through, or comparing properties then you can just use them as normal. For example;

```
class="${document.isCurrent ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}"
```

or;

```
class="${(document.title == selectedDocument.title) ? 'selected' : 'notSelected'}"
```